# Using Tweepy with Apigee

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy, apigee

I am using Tweepy, but I am trying to use it with the api from apigee, but to do so would require me to change `auth.py` https://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/auth.py it looks like and remake the package some how. Is there anyways to use tweepy with another api? Or another way to set up Python to use OAuth but with an apigee api which is connected to Twitter.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: need to sign requests as if they're going to Twitter but then to route them via Apigee (i.e. a proxy use-case).

Longer response with links here:
http://support.apigee.com/apigee/topics/using_python_and_apigees_twitter_api_with_oauth

Comment: I run Twitter Three-legged OAuth Example;

where the consumer_key and consumer_secret are for my APP

Authorize it and enter in the PIN number then to see if it works at the end of the program I added:

`request_token_url = "http://api-user.apigee.com/1/statuses..."
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET", PROXY_DOMAIN)
print resp
print content`

But it still uses the non-OAuth log in.

Thanks,

Comment: I was able to get it working using the Twitter Three-legged OAuth Example. Alternatively one can use the `tweepy` module to do the OAuth part.